# Redirect After Adding a New User in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

This snippet redirect after adding a new user in wordpress. This is useful if you have added customized user fields that need to be set immediately after adding a new user. But not working on wordpres 5.7.

The redirect link shows like that : http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/users.php?id=8

The desired display should be: http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=8

```
add_action("admin_init", "redirect_user_add");
function redirect_user_add() {
    if(!empty($_GET['usersearch'])) {
        $username = $_GET['usersearch'];
        $user = get_userdatabylogin($username);
        wp_redirect( admin_url("/user-edit.php?user_id=".$user->ID) );
    }
}
```

How can i do this .

Comment: From where you adding a new user?

Comment: Backend @Bhautik admin crates new user.